# High Chart not load in Safari browser

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, highcharts

i am using Highchart to display charts in my Application. Now this charts are perfectly working in any other browser except Safari browser. highcharts are not loaded in dafari browser. Below is my code to display data:

```
function Bloodfunction(data) {
            var BloodPressureCurrentDate = $('#txtDate').val();
            DataHR = data;
            var userid = $("#<%=useriddata.ClientID%>").val();
            var Authorizationdata = $("#<%=Authorizationdata.ClientID %>").val();
            var YAsisLabel;
            var UserName;
            var Url = "/IntelliHAPIs/api/TrendChart/GetParameters?userId=" + userid + "&ChartName=BloodPressure&N=" + 10 + "&BoodPresure=" + parseInt(data) + "&BloodPressureCurrentDate=" + BloodPressureCurrentDate;
            $.ajax({
                url: Url,
                crossDomain: true,
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(Authorizationdata)) //Some characters have been replaced for security but this is a true BASE64 of "username:password"
                },
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (chartdata) {

                    var FactoreSB = [];
                    var FactoreDB = [];
                    var FactoreHR = [];
                    var GoalRangeSB = [];
                    var GoalRangeLimitSB = [];

                    var GoalRangeDB = [];
                    var GoalRangeLimitDB = [];


                    var NormalRangeLimitDB = [];
                    var NormalRangeLimitHR = [];
                    var SBgoalPoints = [];
                    var Goallimit = [];
                    var Goallimitline = [];
                    var ChartName;
                    var subChartName;
                    UserName = chartdata["PatientName"];
                    if (chartdata["DataPointsSB"] != null) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < chartdata["DataPointsSB"].length; i++) {
                            FactoreSBRange(FactoreSB, "DataPointsSB", chartdata, i, "GoalPointsSB", GoalRangeSB, GoalRangeLimitSB);
                        }
                    }
                    if (chartdata["DataPointsDB"] != null) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < chartdata["DataPointsDB"].length; i++) {
                            FactoreSBRange(FactoreDB, "DataPointsDB", chartdata, i, "GoalPointsDB", GoalRangeDB, GoalRangeLimitDB);
                        }
                    }
                    if (chartdata["DataPointsHR"] != null) {

                        for (var i = 0; i < chartdata["DataPointsHR"].length; i++) {
                            FactoreSBRange(FactoreHR, "DataPointsHR", chartdata, i, "NormalRangePointsHR", NormalRangeLimitHR, GoalRangeLimitDB);
                        }
                    }

                    var options = new Object();
                    options.series = new Array();
                    if (data == 1) {
                        ChartName = "Blood Pressure";
                        subChartName = "SBP & DBP";
                        YAsisLabe = "mm Hg";
                        var sb = 0;
                        var db;
                        if (chartdata["DataPointsSB"] != null) {
                            //createSeriesObject(options.series, FactoreSB, "SBP", 0);
                            options.series[0] = new Object();
                            options.series[0].name = "SBP";
                            options.series[0].data = FactoreSB;
                            options.series[0].type = 'spline';
                            options.series[0].color = '#6699FF';
                            options.series[0].plotOptions = {
                                spline: {
                                    marker: {
                                        enable: false
                                    }
                                }
                            };
                            if (chartdata["GoalPointsSB"] != null) {

                                if (GoalRangeSB != 0) {
                                    createSeriesObjectRange(options.series, GoalRangeSB, "SBP Goal", 1);
                                }
                                else {
                                    createSeriesObjectRange(options.series, GoalRangeLimitSB, "SBP Goal", 1);
                                }

                            }
                            sb = 1;
                        }
                        else {

                            //createSeriesObject(options.series, FactoreDB, "DBP", 0);
                            options.series[0] = new Object();
                            options.series[0].name = "DBP";
                            options.series[0].data = FactoreDB;
                            options.series[0].type = 'spline';
                            options.series[0].plotOptions = {
                                spline: {
                                    marker: {
                                        enable: false
                                    }
                                }
                            };
                            if (chartdata["GoalPointsDB"] != null) {

                                if (GoalRangeDB != 0) {
                                    createSeriesObjectRange(options.series, GoalRangeDB, "DBP Goal", 1);
                                }
                                else {
                                    createSeriesObjectRange(options.series, GoalRangeLimitDB, "DBP Goal", 1);
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        if (chartdata["DataPointsDB"] != null) {
                            if (sb == 1) {
                                createSeriesObject(options.series, FactoreDB, "DBP", 2);
                                options.series[2] = new Object();
                                options.series[2].name = "DBP";
                                options.series[2].data = FactoreDB;
                                options.series[2].type = 'spline';
                                options.series[2].color = '#00CC00';

                                options.series[2].plotOptions = {
                                    spline: {
                                        marker: {
                                            enable: false
                                        }
                                    }
                                };
                                if (chartdata["GoalPointsDB"] != null) {

                                    if (GoalRangeDB != 0) {
                                        createSeriesObjectRange(options.series, GoalRangeDB, "DBP Goal", 3);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        createSeriesObjectRange(options.series, GoalRangeLimitDB, "DBP Goal", 3);
                                    }

                                }
                            }

                        }




                    }
                    else {
                        ChartName = "Blood Pressure";
                        subChartName = "Heart Rate";
                        YAsisLabe = "bpm";
                        if (chartdata["DataPointsHR"] != null) {

                            //createSeriesObject(options.series, FactoreHR, "Heart Rate", 0);
                            options.series[0] = new Object();
                            options.series[0].name = "Heart Rate";
                            options.series[0].data = FactoreHR;
                            options.series[0].type = 'spline';
                            options.series[0].plotOptions = {
                                spline: {
                                    marker: {
                                        enable: false
                                    }
                                }
                            };
                            if (chartdata["NormalRangePointsHR"] != null) {
                                createSeriesObjectRange(options.series, NormalRangeLimitHR, "Normal Range Heart Rate", 1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //Chart Information
                    if (chartdata["DataPointsSB"] != null || chartdata["DataPointsHR"] != null || chartdata["DataPointsDB"] != null) {

                        //CREATE CHART FOR CONTAINER DIV
                        // document.getElementById('container2').innerHTML = "";
                        $('#container2').highcharts({
                            chart: {
                                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                                plotBorderWidth: null,
                                plotShadow: false,
                                style: {

                                    color: "red",
                                    fontFamily: '\'Lato\', sans-serif',
                                    lineHeight: '18px',
                                    fontSize: '19px',
                                    fontweight: '900'
                                }
                            },
                            title: {//TOP MESSAGE INFORMAITON 
                                text: UserName + ", Latest " + 10 + " Reading ," + ChartName + " - " + subChartName,
                                x: -20 //center

                            },
                            xAxis: {

                                type: 'datetime',

                                dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year


                                    month: ' %e.%b \'%y',
                                    day: ' %e.%b'

                                },
                                title: {
                                    text: ''
                                }
                            },
                            yAxis: {
                                title: {
                                    text: "---" + YAsisLabe + "---"
                                },
                                min: 0
                            },
                            plotOptions: {
                                spline: {
                                    marker: {
                                        enabled: true
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            series: options.series

                        });
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById('container2').innerHTML = "";
                        document.getElementById('container2').innerHTML = "Data does not exist";
                    }

                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(xhr));
                }
            });


        }

function FactoreSBRange(FactoreValueArrayName, chartdataName, chartdata, loopvalue, NormalRangeName, NormalArrayGoalName, NormalArrayGoalLimitName) {
            var loop = parseInt(loopvalue);
            var dateinfo = chartdata[chartdataName][loop].Date1.split("T");
            var hour = dateinfo[1].split(":");
            var hour1 = hour[0];
            var min = hour[1];
            var mydate = dateinfo[0].split('-');
            var month = mydate[1];
            var year = mydate[0];
            var day = mydate[2];
            var date = dateinfo[0] + " " + dateinfo[1],
            values = date.split(/[^0-9]/),
            yearNew = parseInt(values[0], 10),
            monthNew = parseInt(values[1], 10) - 1,
            dayNew = parseInt(values[2], 10),
            hoursNew = parseInt(values[3], 10),
            minutesNew = parseInt(values[4], 10),
            secondsNew = parseInt(values[5], 10),
            formattedDateNew;

            formattedDateNew = new Date(yearNew, monthNew, dayNew, hoursNew, minutesNew, secondsNew);
            var newdate = formattedDateNew
            //var date = "2013-05-12 20:00:00",

            //var daty = parseInt(day).toString();
            var daty = parseInt(dayNew).toString();
            var chartDatainfo = chartdata;
            FactoreValueArrayName[loop] = [];

            FactoreValueArrayName[loop][0] = Date.UTC(newdate.getFullYear(), newdate.getMonth(), daty);
            FactoreValueArrayName[loop][1] = parseInt(chartdata[chartdataName][loopvalue].Value);
            DataPointDate = Date.UTC(newdate.getFullYear(), newdate.getMonth(), parseInt(daty));
            var teampdata;
            if (DataPointDate < teampdata) {
                DataPointDate = teampdata;
            } else {
                teampdata = DataPointDate;
                DataPointDate = teampdata;
            }
            if (chartdata[NormalRangeName] != null) {

                var normaldata = chartdata[NormalRangeName];
                if (DataHR == 1)
                    GoalRangeInf(loop, NormalArrayGoalName, NormalRangeName, chartDatainfo, NormalArrayGoalLimitName);
                else
                    NormalRangeInf(loop, NormalRangeName, NormalArrayGoalName, chartDatainfo);
                //NormalRangeInf(loop, normalRangeName, normalRangeArray, chartdata)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ok, and what errors do you have in Javascript console?

Comment: there is no error in javascript but charts are not loaded in safari browser

Comment: Interesting. I guess then formatting your data fails. Could you attach `FactoreSBRange` method? And data sample which fails to render in Safari? Also, which Safari version you mean? I think, that reason is Date() object, where your data isn't in proper format for JS.

Comment: yes you are right safari browser get invalid date error

Comment: Date is in "Thu Jun 18 2015 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" formate, this date is working fine in any browser except safari

Comment: That means you need to change format to supported one. Or, even better, in the backend translate dates into timestamps and then send them to the browser. Note: JS requires timestamps in milliseconds.

Comment: i already convert date into timestamp, please check my code

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see your updated code? Neither data or `FactoreSBRange` method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help. I just found the answer. error was occurred in FactoreSBRange of Date invalid. Safari browser take date as invalid error. so i convert date as below:

```
function FactoreSBRange(FactoreValueArrayName, chartdataName, chartdata, loopvalue, NormalRangeName, NormalArrayGoalName, NormalArrayGoalLimitName) {
            var loop = parseInt(loopvalue);
            var dateinfo = chartdata[chartdataName][loop].Date1.split("T");
            var hour = dateinfo[1].split(":");
            var hour1 = hour[0];
            var min = hour[1];
            var mydate = dateinfo[0].split('-');
            var month = mydate[1];
            var year = mydate[0];
            var day = mydate[2];
            var date = dateinfo[0] + " " + dateinfo[1],
            values = date.split(/[^0-9]/),
            yearNew = parseInt(values[0], 10),
            monthNew = parseInt(values[1], 10) - 1,
            dayNew = parseInt(values[2], 10),
            hoursNew = parseInt(values[3], 10),
            minutesNew = parseInt(values[4], 10),
            secondsNew = parseInt(values[5], 10),
            formattedDateNew;

            formattedDateNew = new Date(yearNew, monthNew, dayNew, hoursNew, minutesNew, secondsNew);
            var newdate = formattedDateNew
            //var date = "2013-05-12 20:00:00",

            //var daty = parseInt(day).toString();
            var daty = parseInt(dayNew).toString();
            var chartDatainfo = chartdata;
            FactoreValueArrayName[loop] = [];

            FactoreValueArrayName[loop][0] = Date.UTC(newdate.getFullYear(), newdate.getMonth(), daty);
            FactoreValueArrayName[loop][1] = parseInt(chartdata[chartdataName][loopvalue].Value);
            DataPointDate = Date.UTC(newdate.getFullYear(), newdate.getMonth(), parseInt(daty));
            var teampdata;
            if (DataPointDate < teampdata) {
                DataPointDate = teampdata;
            } else {
                teampdata = DataPointDate;
                DataPointDate = teampdata;
            }
            if (chartdata[NormalRangeName] != null) {

                var normaldata = chartdata[NormalRangeName];
                if (DataHR == 1)
                    GoalRangeInf(loop, NormalArrayGoalName, NormalRangeName, chartDatainfo, NormalArrayGoalLimitName);
                else
                    NormalRangeInf(loop, NormalRangeName, NormalArrayGoalName, chartDatainfo);
                //NormalRangeInf(loop, normalRangeName, normalRangeArray, chartdata)
            }
        }
```

In the code given above newdate given error as invalid date so i converted it as show in code and my issue is resolved.